# About the eigenvectors of a matrix related to a Cayley graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

In some papers about the cayley graphs of finite groups the behaviour of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\phi$ were discussed when $\phi=\sum_{g\in G} \lambda_G(g)$ and $\lambda_G(g)$ is defined by $\lambda_G(g)\delta_v=\delta_{gv}$  where $\delta_g(a)=1$ if $g=a$ and for other elements of $G$ the value of $\delta_g(a)=0$.
It is proved that $\chi\in Irr(G)$ satisfies the following relation and so $\chi$ is an eigenvector of $\phi$:

$$\phi(\chi)=(\sum_{i=1}^h {|K_i|\chi(k_i)\over \chi(1)})\chi$$
when $K_i$ is a conjugacy class of $G$ and $k_i\in K_i$.

It is stated that this result can proved by showing that $\theta=\phi(\chi)$ satisfies 5.4 in "Character theory: Feit" as follows:
$$\theta(g)\theta(h)={\theta(1)\over |G|}\sum_{t\in G} \theta(gt^{-1}ht)$$
for each $g,h\in G$. But I have no idea how we can show this result.

Could you kindly help me for proving this result.

Comment: Which "some papers"?

Comment: total perfect codes in cayley graph by Zhou, Des. Codes and Cryptogr. 2016

Comment: Also in Etienne, Perfect codes and regular partitions in graphs and groups, Eur. J. Combin. 1987

Comment: Does my correction get your intent right?

Comment: Okay, let me prove your first formula independently of whatever Feit has done. First of all, the sum on the right hand side is simply $\dfrac{\sum_{g \in G}\chi\left(g\right)}{\chi\left(1\right)}$. But character orthogonality shows that $\sum_{g \in G}\chi\left(g\right)$ equals $\left|G\right|$ when $\chi$ is the trivial character, and equals $0$ otherwise (see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908947/sum-of-an-irreducible-character-over-all-g ). The case when $\chi$ is the trivial character is easy (indeed, in this case we have $\lambda_G \left(g\right) \chi = \chi$ for ...

Comment: ... all $g \in G$, so that $\phi\left(\chi\right) = \left|G\right|\chi$); thus, it remains to consider the other case. In that other case (i.e., when $\chi$ is not trivial), we must show that $\phi\left(\chi\right) = 0$. Well, write $\chi$ as $\chi = \sum_{h \in G} \chi\left(h\right) \delta_h$, and apply $\phi$ to obtain $\phi\left(\chi\right) = \sum_{g \in G} \sum_{h \in G} \chi\left(h\right) \lambda_G\left(g\right) \delta_h = \sum_{g \in G} \sum_{h \in G} \chi\left(h\right) \delta_{gh}$. The coefficient of $\delta_u$ (for a given $u \in G$) on the right hand side of this ...

Comment: ... equality is $\sum_{\left(g, h\right) \in G \times G;\ gh = u} \chi\left(h\right) = \sum_{g \in G} \chi\left(g\right) = 0$, and thus we conclude that $\phi\left(\chi\right) = 0$, as desired.

Comment: (Note: I'm assuming that $\lambda_G$ is the action of $G$ on its own group ring. If not, this is probably subtler.)